# How to render widgets under notch in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

By default, Flutter respects the `SafeArea` around the notch.

After `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` (to remove time, overlay etc.) then setting `SafeArea` to `false` on all sides, there is still a blank area around the notch:

[image]

How can I make the app render without considering the notch? i.e. the `AppBar` should display under the black notch area.

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      left: false,
      right: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'hello stack overflow',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to have a straight appbar under the black area?

Comment: Yes that's right, I'm going to use it to make some screenshots without the notch